# How to retrieve Outlook EntryID and send outlook mail item as attachment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

i'm very new to excel vba and vba. In my organization, we have an email automation where email is sent using outlook via excel vba to the user. I want to send a follow up email without creating a new mail each time, and I want them to be send in the same thread as the first mail. In order to do that, I need an EntryID. I did my google-ing before asking here and it seemed like I can't find any answers as to how to retrieve outlook EntryID. Also, how to attach an outlook mail item to the email, using the email automation. For example, I want to send a new email to the recipient, and I also want to attached the previous mail that I send him. Can you help me, thank you.

Comment: improve your question including images or part of your script

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are having troubles retrieving the entry id of the message in the Sent Items folder sine it changes when a message is sent and moved to the Sent Items folder. Use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder to record the entry id.